# Trying to reverse 123 _> 321 using int Java

Tags: java, methods, return, reverse

I have been tasked with creating a method that will take a 3 digit input from the user and reverse its order, then return it back in that new order, without converting anything into a string, it all stays as an int. I cannot figure out how to return the new number without adding the values together (first second third);

```
public class Lab01
{

   public int sumTheDigits(int num)
   {
      int one;
      int two;
      int three;

      one = num % 10;
      two = (num/10) % 10;
      three = num / 100;

      return one + two + three;
   }

   public int reverseTheOrder(int num)
   {
      int first;
      int second;
      int third;

      third = num / 100;
      second = (num/10) % 10;
      first = num % 10;


      return ?;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

      Lab01 lab = new Lab01();
      System.out.println("Enter a three digit number: ");
      int theNum = input.nextInt();
      int theSum = lab.sumTheDigits(theNum);
      int theReverse = lab.reverseTheOrder(theSum);

      System.out.println("The sum of the digits of " + theNum + " is " + theSum);
      System.,out.println(theNum + " reversed is " + theReverse);



   }

}
```

Comment: You can't just add three singe-digit numbers and expect  three-digit number. You need to use the powers of ten. If you have them in a, b, and c, and want to display them as abc, then you need to do something like (a * 100) + (b * 10) + c.

Comment: thank you so much, thats so simple wish i would have noticed it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for any number length

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num = 0;
        int reversenum = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = in.nextInt();
        while (num != 0) {
            reversenum = reversenum * 10;
            reversenum = reversenum + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse number is: " + reversenum);
    }
```